# Contest is over. Can I see my ranking?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

In Tuber Simulator, a contest has just ended. I don't seem to have made the top 500 (the only ones that are shown), but still, I would like to see where I ranked. Maybe not a full on ranking #, but at least how much people liked my room.

Can I have access to this information, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't find what place you would had gotten if you fail to make the grade. Tuber Simulator only keeps the data for the top 500 Tubers until the leaderboard expires.

I know, as I also failed to make the grade as well. And so I can't see how many likes I got on my room. All I know is that it is at most the number of likes 500 got - but I possibly wouldn't had got them fast enough.

Comment: But not even the number of hearts I got?

Comment: Nope. Not even that.